# How to get the name of the base class from a derived class in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get the name of the base class from a derived class using reflection.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting it, but your question and title seem to contradict each other.

Comment: I am sorry if my question is not clear, but i have got the answer i was looking for. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 6):

```
Type type = typeof(Derived);
Type baseType = type.BaseType;
if(baseType != null) {
    string baseTypeName = baseType.Name;
    Console.WriteLine(baseTypeName);
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("No base type.");
}
```

Alternatively you can use [`Type.FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx) if you want the fully-qualified name.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the simple name:

```
var name = typeof(DerivedType).BaseType.Name;
```

Or if you want the assembly qualified name:

```
var name = typeof(DerivedType).BaseType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

If you want code that won't throw a null reference exception:

```
var type = typeof(DerivedType);
var parentType = type.BaseType;

if(parentType != null)
{
    var name = parentType.Name;
    var assemblyQualifiedName = parentType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
}
```

Comment: It's `Type.BaseType` not `Type.BaseClass`.

Answer (score 2):

`BaseClassInstance.GetType().BaseType.FullName;` should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

You can get it like this:

```
    class BaseClass { }
    class DerivedClass : BaseClass { }

    [Test]
    public void TestBaseName()
    {
        var a = new DerivedClass();
        Assert.AreEqual(a.GetType().BaseType.Name, "BaseClass");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I find NUnit to assist greatly when writing example code, since before posting it, I can verify it actually works.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure what your question meant. You've already gotten a few answers showing you how to get the base type from the derived type.

```
Type baseType = type.BaseType;
```

To go the other way if you have a reference of a base type, you can use GetType to get the dynamic type:

```
BaseClass foo = ....;
Type type = foo.GetType();
```

Answer (score 1):

Some reflection might do the magic:

```
var type = this.GetType();
while(type.BaseType != typeof(object))
{
    type = type.BaseType;
}
Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ChildClass cc = new ChildClass();
string baseNameClass = cc.GetType().BaseType.FullName;
```